# Platform for running Hadoop with Hbase

Tags: java, hadoop

We were just going to start working with a project using Hadoop and Hbase and were confused about which platform to use for it. It seems Hadoop is actually made for unix based systems but seems it also can be run in windows with the help of cygwin.

Will we have to face any specific issues incase Windows is selected or will it run equally good as any Unix based systems. Our project is based on sorting out data created by a web crawler and creating a simple searching interface using map/reduce technique.

If someone experienced could lay down about differences in using Windows / Unix based like Ubuntu.

ps:we are more comfortable working in windows

Comment: IMO it's a lot easier, when getting started, to use the Cloudera VM image.

Comment: Hadoop on Windows is not supported for production and Microsoft works to fix this. So you will run into problems one way or another because why should Microsoft bother if there are no problems.

Answer (score 1):

As of now Hadoop is not recommend in production on a Windows box. HortonWorks and Microsoft are working on migrating Hadoop to Windows Server and Azure. Currently it's in [developer preview](https://www.hadooponazure.com/) and it might be some time before it's stable and open for public usage.  For development purpose  Hadoop on Windows should be OK, I am not sure but some of the Hadoop features might not work. Here is a [tutorial](http://v-lad.org/Tutorials/Hadoop/00%20-%20Intro.html) for setting Hadoop on Windows.

> ps:we are more comfortable working in windows

As mentioned in the comments, there are a couple of VMs for Hadoop on Linux which can be installed on a VM Player or a VirtualBox hypervisor. Here is a [tutorial](http://www.thecloudavenue.com/2011/12/getting-started-with-hadoop-is-easy.html) on getting started with Cloudera CDH on VirtualBox. Cloudera CDH VM has got couple of Apache frameworks (Hadoop, Pig, Hive, Sqoop, HBase etc) installed, configured and well integrated and tested. Another option is to use [Amazon EMR](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticmapreduce/) for getting started easily.

BTW, I would also suggest to get comfortable with Linux environments and get used to it. Linux is a lot more fun than other OS. There are lot of tutorials/articles on how to get started including [this](http://www.thecloudavenue.com/search/label/gettingstarted).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have choosen Ubuntu for now.